# Dropdown Menu and PHP

Tags: php

I am new in coding. I started learn PHP and I got into a problem that I tried to catch the data from dropdown menu and print it inside the same code via PHP. But the problem is when I try to select it doesn't show anything. Please help!

```
    <?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $code = $_POST['coder'];
    echo "You are ".$code." coder";
  }
?>

<form action="" method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Languages: </td>
            <td>
                <select name="coder">
                    <option>Select One</option>
                    <option value="JAVA">JAVA</option>
                    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
                    <option value="C#">C#</option>
                    <option value="C++">C++</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value ="Submit">
                <input type="reset" value="Clear">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] as introduction. Concerning your problem, please extract a [mcve] and provide that as part of your question. Also, provide the steps to reproduce this, i.e. what you did and where you clicked. If possible, prefer using PHP's builtin webserver in those instructions.

Answer (score 2):

`isset($_POST['submit'])` becoming `false` because there is no any element with name `"submit"`. Try setting name to submit button as.

```
<input type="submit" value ="Submit" name="submit">
```